# How To Use ShadowJar To Create A Jar File

Tags: java, shadowjar

Recently found out about gradle and really struggling to use [ShadowJar](https://imperceptiblethoughts.com/shadow/configuration/#configuring-output-name)

Despite reading it repeatedly as i'm a slow learner (Just figured out how to add gradle dependency after a couple of weeks and still confused at how to configure ShadowJar) it keeps showing the error

Input

```
java -jar GradleTestJava-1.0-SNAPSHOT-all.jar
```

Output

```
Error: Could not find or load main class Com.TEST.Main.main
```

I stumbled on this to add the following to gradle build

```
jar {

    manifest {

        attributes(

                'Main-Class': 'Com.TEST.Main.main'

        )

    }

}
```

it stills throws the error as i'm completely stuck for about a week i hope someone can help me